# SignalR Script - MimeType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in my MVC 4 application.  When doing so I get the following error:

Refused to execute script from '[myappname]/signalr/hubs' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Any ideas why this would fail?

Comment: Update all of your packages, in particular Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

Comment: Ok.  That seemed to work.  I updated to 2.0 (RC).  Thanks!